# Add route to view in flask-admin

Tags: flask, flask-admin

so basically I'm trying to add a custom endpoint to my Flask + Flask-Admin app that allows admins to download a CSV.

Something like this:

```
class MyAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('admin/home.html')

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.has_role('admin')

    @expose('/csv-export')
    def csv_export(self):
        batch_num = request.args.get('batch_num')

        if not batch_num:
            flash('Invalid batch id', 'danger')
            abort(404)

        si = io.StringIO()
        cw = csv.writer(si)

        rows = MyObj.query.filter_by(batch_num=batch_num).all()

        cw.writerows(rows)
        output = make_response(si.getvalue())
        output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
        output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
        return output
```

But if I add this to my base admin view, the '/csv-export' route doesn't register and I get a 404.

I guess I could add an entirely new Blueprint just for this endpoint but it seems like a lot of work for a simple endpoint that doesn't require a separate template view. Any tips?

Comment: what url do you try to get a 404 ? and how do you register the view (`admin.add_view(MyAdminIndexView...`) ?

Comment: Nevermind, this was a problem with my docker build. Even tho i have debug mode on, the flask server wasn't rebuilding on the docker container. I have no idea why.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because person who asked the question says it was a problem he had with Docker.